# GCC suppress flags

Tags: gcc, linker-errors, vxworks

I'm trying to create a shared library with my gcc. It's a gcc for vxworks (thats probably the problem...).

I use the gcc as following:

```
./gcc -shared -B/path/to/gnutools/bin -o test.so test.c
```

Result:

```
/path/to/ld: -r and -shared may not be used together 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I try the same with the linux gcc, there's no problem. So i guess the gcc for VxWorks automatically passes the -r (or -i, which is the same and results in the same) flag to the linker. Is there a way to suppress this?

Greetz

marty

PS: making it static is not really an alternative...

Comment: What is ./gcc? Is it a shellscript that you could view, and create an edited copy of, to remove the -r?

Comment: Yes, it's a shellscript. But theres no -r or -i in it. I just added the -B (Binaries) and -I (Includes) pathes. And it doesn't change anything if i call the gcc directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try compile object file separately with -fPIC and then link:

```
    gcc -Wall -fPIC -c -o test.o test.c
    gcc -Wall -shared -o test.so test.o
```

Another suggestion is to use libtool (at least to figure out the correct flags).

A workaround may be to go directly with `ld`:

```
    ld -shared -o test.so test.o -lc
```

Comment: result is still the same... still wondering where the -r is comming from. libtool seems to be for linux. I need it for VxWorks. But thanx for the ideas :)

Comment: jeah your workaround rly works. Thanx. Just still working on it, because i need the gcc to link it, because of other parameters. For example i have to include other libraries.

Comment: You can keep using `ld` for linking. Other libraries are passed to gcc with Makefile variables like `LIBS` or `LDADD`; but gcc just passes them to `ld` underneath. So you can just pass these variables directly to ld.